# Bootstrap not workig

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular 4 app.

I've installed both Bootstrap 4 and NG Bootstrap:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Now in *package.json* I have:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
  "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
  "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
}
```

and in *app.module.ts*:

```
...
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    NgbModule.forRoot()
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
...
```

This is all I did. Bootstrap has no effect on my pages at all.

Previously I was using Bootstrap v3.3.7 which was working properly. At that time I had the css and jquery references added in *.angular-cli.json*.

Now I don't have these as the docs say I don't need them. (Out of curiosity I tried adding them anyway and it gave my pages some very limited ugly Bootstrap look, that's all.)

What can be the problem?

Comment: When you say "no effect on my pages" does that mean you have tried the ng-bootstrap directives? for example the button directive: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples and that did not work?

Also, you do not need to install `bootstrap` if what you're after is ng-bootstrap directives.

If you do need bootstrap (for styling) then yes, you have to include it in your `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: Good question because now you made me see that maybe I'm mixing up things here a little. I installed NG Bootstrap because I thought that's the way how one integrates Bootstrap into an Angular app. But I'm not using any *ng-bootstrap* directives at all. I'm taking the components from [getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/] . So maybe I don't need NG Bootstrap at all? Just need to do `npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-beta` and that was it? And maybe also add `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` to the styles in `angular-cli.json`?

Comment: yes, what you described is correct. You do not need `ng-bootstrap` in your case. and you should include the CSS in `styles` and the js in `scripts` of your `.angular-cli.json` the css and js you need are described in the getting started documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: I see that @lingthe added an answer which is exactly what you need, please edit your question to be exactly what you are looking for and accept lingthe answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Angular-CLI you need to add styles and scripts for bootstrap to your angular-cli.json file, like this:

```
... "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js", 
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ], ...
```

Comment: Now it works, thank you. Meanwhile it turned out that the *limited, ugly Bootstrap look* was caused by the migrating from v3 to 4, that some of my components like navigation and panels are not fully supported by v4 the way they are coded in the template files. So these I'll have to update...